# здравствуйте, я новичок и в этом коде я хочу прибавлять каждый год 10% от суммы, но вылазит ошибка: 'int' object is not callable в 6-ой строчке

Tags: python-2.x

```
def bank(a,year1,year2):
    a = int(a)
    year1 = int(year1)
    year2 = int(year2)
    r = year2 - year1
    s = a + r(a/10)
    return s
bank(5000,2016,2022)
```

Answer (score 1):

посмотрите на эту строку

```
s = a + r(a/10)
```

В математике можно пропускать иногда знак умножения. А вот при программировании на питоне - нет. Знак умножения десь обязателен.  Также, питон (как и 99% языков) не может догадаться, что Вы хотите сделать - все должно быть явно. В самом конце Вы вызываете функцию bank, но никак не обрабатываете ее результат. Скорее всего хочется просто распечатать.

```
def bank(a,year1,year2):
    a = int(a)
    year1 = int(year1)
    year2 = int(year2)
    r = year2 - year1
    s = a + r*(a/10)
    return s
print(bank(5000,2016,2022))
```

Но если честно, то мне кажется, что тут задача на сложные проценты и она решена неверно.